# How to save the pictures on this internet page?

Tags: copy-paste, pictures, save-as

There are these charts in [this web page](http://uis.unesco.org/apps/visualisations/research-and-development-spending/), and I want to save them. How is that possible. The usual "save picture as" is not there in the right click.

Comment: That's because they aren't pictures.  Use a screenshot tool that lets you select an area to capture.

Comment: @fixer1234 Like what?

Comment: Like whatever you want.  There are endless choices.  Your OS (which you don't mention) may have a screenshot utility.  There are lots of browser add-ons and stand-alone utilities.  They range from simple screen grabbers to ones with lots of features to select what you want, even to edit and annotate the image after it's captured.  Just google "screenshot" or look in your browser add-ons store.  You may already have one loaded on your machine because they a commonly-included utility.

Comment: @fixer1234 Would be a good idea to combine your both comments into an answer.

Comment: Do you have permission to do this from the website owner?

Comment: @Dave It is a UNESCO website. How can I find out whether I have permission?

Comment: No idea, but you need to consider this because taking content which may break any rule/law etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The charts aren't pictures, so there isn't an image there to download.  They appear to be created on the page by applets, so what you're looking at is really more of a program.  If you want an image, you basically need to create one by capturing the displayed result.

You can do that with a screenshot (or "screen grabber") utility.  These capture the pixels comprising the screen content and save it as an image file.

These utilities are ubiquitous and most are free.  Most OSes either bundle one or offer a selection of them in their repository or store.  The major browsers also offer a selection of them in the form of add-ons, and there are lots of available third party utilities.  Googling "screenshot" will identify options as well as reviews and recommendations.

I won't recommend a specific one, because availability will vary by OS, and there is a big range of features; what is best for any user will be a personal preference.  But one that at least lets you define a rectangular selection area will save you some work getting to a final image.